Type annotation of fixpoint combinator intereferes with Lean4's strictness
As many people already know, it's not possible to implement a Y combinator in a strict language using the following combinator $\mathsf{M},\,\mathsf{W}$ where
$$
\mathsf{M} = \lambda x.x\ x;\quad\mathsf{W}=\lambda x.\lambda y.x\ (y\ y).
$$
and $ \mathsf{Y} = \mathsf{M}\ \mathsf{W}$.
In Lean, this would be
unsafe inductive μ : Type -> Type
  | fold : (μ α -> α) -> μ α

unsafe abbrev unfold : μ α -> μ α -> α
  | .fold f => f

unsafe abbrev M (x : μ α) : α := unfold x x

unsafe abbrev W (t : α -> α) : μ α := .fold λ f : μ α => t (unfold f f)

unsafe def fix (t : α -> α) :=
  M $ W t

def genfact (f : Nat -> Nat) n :=
  if n = 0 then 1 else n * f (n - 1)

#eval fix genfact 25

My expectation is for this code to not work. -- And indeed it stackoverflows.
However, if I change the type of t to (α -> α) -> α -> α in fix (Which causes the α in W and fix to be unified with α = α -> α), it magically works. This has been troubling me as I thought Lean is a strict language (and according to De Moura), but somehow I can still manage to get fix working by just modifying its argument type. In contrast to other languages like OCaml I've tested, this implementation just straight up stackoverflows.
PS: I'm not sure which stackexchange to post as my question does not involve 'proving' but since it's a Lean related problem so I posted here.

This happens because the lean compiler implicitly eta-expands functions during compilation. So this function:
unsafe def fix (t : (α → α) → (α → α)) : α → α :=
  M $ W t

is interpreted by the compiler as
unsafe def fix (t : (α → α) → (α → α)) : α → α :=
  fun x => M (W t) x

which in particular will not run the application M (W t) until x is also passed. This expansion does not happen when fix is just a generic function.
This is a weird and counterintuitive behavior of the compiler which is arguably a bug (https://github.com/leanprover/lean4/issues/5908), but is unlikely to change in the near term for reasons discussed on the issue.

Thank you, this answered my question. In a sense this eta-expansion (I think scala has this feature..?) caused Lean to be not as strict as some other languages like OCaml.
